# Node.js core dumps on Windows 7

Tags: node.js

I am on windows 7 and installed Node.js using this tutorial:
http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs

When I am trying to run the tests , everything "CRASHES" (I don`t know why) and when I am running this line "node server.js" I am getting this error : "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

What to do?

Thanks a lot,
Yosy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [official node installation guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation), and make sure all your dependencies are met.

Remember you can always stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

What version of node do you use?

0.5.x are not compatible with Cygwin and future releases will not be compatible.

0.4.11 should work.